# Wireless keyboard not detected by AVD emulator on Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-keyboard, android-studio

I am debugging some apps using the Android AVD images running in the emulator on Linux, however, I am not able to type anything with the wireless keyboard, I can't replicate this issue on Windows or OSX, though I have been able to verify this on at least 2 different linux boxes with 2 different keyboard brands, an usb keyboard works just fine. How can I go about this? Is this related to x/wayland? or is this an issue with the android emulator? I'm on Fedora 25 x64 with the latest updates and using the android tools (build-tools, platform-tools and sdk-tools) version 25.

Comment: Are you running X or Wayland? Keyboard handling is completely different for both. Is the emulator an X application (accessing Wayland through a compatibility layer), or a native Wayland application?

Comment: I am on Fedora 25, so I assume I am running Wayland and as for the emulator I can also assume it works through a compatibility layer.